# Overflow horizontal in jsPlomb, line dont work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jsplumb

In my project we are using the jsPlomb for connect cards with dynamic mode, this is an example:
[image]

And this happens when use the scroll lateral:

[image]

I tried to use the jsPlomb.repaintEverything(), but don't work. How i can fixed that ?